# Replacing cast iron hot water floor standing radiator with wall mounted type

Tags: radiator

How does one size the replacement radiator to approximate the old radiator output, or should I just do a heating btu calculation from the room dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

For the heat output of the standing cast iron radiator you need to show the name, height, # of sections, # of tubes in each section, then look on a chart for the equivalent sq ft and multiply that # by 240 btu/sq ft